# video HTTP request from wordpress blog

Tags: javascript, json, http, wordpress

I was wondering if there a way to make HTTP request for videos on a WordPress blog? I am coding an app using Jquery mobile. I am able to get recent post through Jason API. But I was wondring it there a way to do the same for videos on the same blog.

Please help. It there a plugin or a paid service? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to display recent uploaded videos to blog page?

Comment: Yes! I ant to be able to display a list of videos from a video page

Comment: From where you are getting video to your video page , from your you tube channel?

Comment: The videos are stored on the websites server using easy video player 2

Comment: so you are uploading video by creating post? in video page?

Comment: Yes basically. So it all within the WordPress blog database

Comment: But if that is also post type data then you can call it as recent  post..

Comment: Yes. That is true. Is there any plugin or something ?

Comment: you can call recent posts by code :                                         <ul>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<li><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>

Comment: :D I have no idea with PHP. I am only good with js. :(.

Comment: yeah but you can use that my given code to achieve thing as per your question.

Comment: you can ask me here if you have any doubt.

Comment: I dont know if you get my question clearly. But Same as JSON API plugin, I am able to get post via Javascript HTTP request. And I need a way to do the same using Javascript to access videos from a wordpress site